# writing to a file on the -iphone-unwanted symbols

Tags: objective-c

I have an array and i am writing it to a file using :

```
memoryString=[memoryString stringByAppendingString:WhatsTheTimeNow]; 
[memoryFile addObject:memoryString];
[memoryFile writeToFile:fullFileName atomically:NO];
```

the log is ok , But what i get on the log file is also some more symbols :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>  Touch Event: leftEye    --- ר10 10:33:10---2011</string>
    <string>  Sensor Event: rightHand    --- א10 10:33:26---2011</string>
    <string>  Sensor Event: rightHand    --- ר10 10:33:29---2011</string>
    <string>  Sensor Event: rightLeg    --- א10 10:33:32---2011</string>
    <string>  Touch Event: leftEye    --- ר10 10:33:34---2011</string>
    <string>  Touch Event: leftEye    --- א10 10:33:36---2011</string>

</array>
</plist>
```

The problem, is that i dont want that `<string>` ,`<array>`  symbols at the start and end , and the 3 openning lines.
how do i get rid of this symbols ??

thanks alot .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `writeToFile` method will automatically generate a `.plist` which is very convenient for reading it back in. If you would like to roll your own,

```
NSMutableString *file = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSString *s in memoryFile) {
    [file appendFormat:@"%@\n", s];
}
[memoryFile writeToFile:fullFileName atomically:NO 
   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Note that `writeToFile:atomically:` is deprecated.

Your strange characters must stem from some issue with the assignment to `memoryString`.

Answer (score 2):

Those "symbols" are what makes your file a `.plist`, which is what is created when you call `writeToFile:` on an `NSArray`. If you want a custom output (which you won't be able to read back in to an array using standard functionality), you'll have to write it yourself, probably using `NSString`'s `writeToFile:` method instead.